# List linked to Tables in MS Access: Can't update Lists from Access Only Memo/Text Fields

Tags: list, synchronisation, access, microsoft-access

So I have an Access database where I have re-created the tables as SharePoint lists, and then use the MS Access linked table manager to connect. Everything is fine as it should be, only when I go to save data from a form in access, everything saves except memo/multiple lines of text. I get no errors, but when i open up the table (linked table now) those fields are uneditable, while the rest I can change fine?

I made the columns in sharepoint not required, and plain text? Am I missing something simple here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the answer to this question. I was trying to update multiple lines of text from access memo field with DAO VBA code, and the fields were set to rich text.

Once I change to plain text....it worked fine!